# Why does my BroadcastReceiver Doesn't work properly?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-broadcast

I'm stuck in this problem for 3 days and I'm so frustrated ..

I don't know why on earth my BroadCastReceiver doesn't work ...

I'll sincerely appreciate solving my problem...

Here is my code..

MainActivity (I posted some pieces of codes from my whole codes.. that I regard as important to understand) 
This MainActivity, I get AlarmManager..
:

```
public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity implements TabListener{

private GregorianCalendar mCalendar;
private NotificationManager mNotification;
private AlarmManager mManager;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    mNotification = (NotificationManager)getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

    //Get AlarmManager here..
    mManager = (AlarmManager)getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
    ....
        ..
}

    public NotificationManager getNotification(){
        return mNotification;
    }
    public AlarmManager getAlarmManager(){
        return mManager;
    }
```

And here is my MsgBookingFragment(this class extends Fragment..) :

```
    //...somewhere else of my codes..
    //Access to SQLDataBase and get Date, and set it in bookDate..
bookDate.set(Integer.parseInt(year.split("년")[0]),
        Integer.parseInt(month.split("월")[0]), 
        Integer.parseInt(day.split("일")[0]),
        Integer.parseInt(hourOfDay.split("시")[0]), 
        Integer.parseInt(minute.split("분")[0]));


    //get mainActivity, in order to get AlarmManager..
final MainActivity mainActivity = (MainActivity)getActivity();

AlertDialog.Builder alert_confirm = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());

alert_confirm.setMessage("예약 하시겠습니까?").setCancelable(false).setPositiveButton("예",
new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
        doSomething();

        msgViewService.write(vo);
        Log.i("MsgBookingfragment", "msgViewInputVO write done = " + vo.toString());

        FragmentManager FM = getFragmentManager();
        FM.popBackStack();
        FragmentTransaction ft = FM.beginTransaction();


        mainActivity.setHashMapInsert(vo.getPersonID());
        mainActivity.setBookedHashInsert(vo.getPersonID());

        ft.replace(R.id.findperson, new FindPersonFragment()).commit();

        //here, I get AlarmSet Instance and setAlarm..!!
        AlarmSet alarm = new AlarmSet(bookDate, 
                getActivity().getApplicationContext(),
                ((MainActivity)getActivity()).getAlarmManager(),
                ((MainActivity)getActivity()).getNotification() );
        alarm.setAlarm();


        Toast.makeText(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), "예약되었습니다.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
```

And here is my AlarmSet Class :

```
public class AlarmSet extends Activity  implements OnDateChangedListener, OnTimeChangedListener{

 private String tag = "AlarmSet";
    private Calendar bookDate = Calendar.getInstance();
    private Context context;
    private AlarmManager mManager;
    private NotificationManager mNotification;


    public AlarmSet(Calendar cal, Context c,  AlarmManager am, NotificationManager noti){

        bookDate = cal;
        context = c;
        mNotification = noti;
        mManager = am; 
    }

    public void setAlarm() {
        mManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, bookDate.getTimeInMillis(), pendingIntent());
        Log.i("setAlarm : ", bookDate.getTime().toString());

     //Log shows this message : Sat Oct 18 14:25:52 GMT+09:00 2014
    }

    //set free Alarm
    public void resetAlarm() {
        mManager.cancel(pendingIntent());
    }

    public PendingIntent pendingIntent() {
        Intent i = new Intent(context, AlarmReceiver.class);
        PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 3 , i, PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);
        Log.i(tag, "PendingIntent.......");
        return pi;
    }
```

here is my AlarmReceiver :

```
public class AlarmReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver{

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    Log.i("TAg", "ggggggggggggggggggggg");
    Toast.makeText(context, R.string.app_name, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

}
```

And here is my ManiFast :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="org.dduo.hrelation"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_CONTACTS" />
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS" />

        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SEND_SMS" />



    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="11"
        android:targetSdkVersion="17" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >

        <receiver android:name="org.dduo.hrelation.AlarmReceiver">

            <intent-filter>

                <action android:name="action"/>

            </intent-filter>

        </receiver>

        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >



            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>


        </activity>

    </application>



</manifest>
```

So long pieces of codes...

By the way, I reckon it's so doubtful of pendingIntent method... I guess the problem is because of that method.. I've never seen that "ggggggggg" log msg.. and toast msg on my test device..

Please... help me..

Comment: can you post your logcat please .... and the error you are facing will also be appearing in your logcat take a look at that ...

Comment: Your AlarmReceiver is a BroadcastReceiver. Its not Activity. But while creating PendingIntent, you used PendingIntent.getActivity(). and the way you are using Activity in case of AlarmSet is not good

Comment: ----Gopal Rao-- 
would you post some codes for me? I couldn't make out what you mean.. Sorry.. T_T..

Answer (score 0):

```
in  ManiFast :


<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="org.dduo.hrelation"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_CONTACTS" />
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS" />

        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SEND_SMS" />



    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="11"
        android:targetSdkVersion="17" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
//---> declare broadcast receiver like this
        <receiver android:name="org.dduo.hrelation.AlarmReceiver">
            </receiver>

        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >



            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>


        </activity>

    </application>



</manifest>


and pendingIntent():


public PendingIntent pendingIntent() {
        Intent i = new Intent(context, AlarmReceiver.class);
        PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(getApplicationContext(), 0, i, 0);
        Log.i(tag, "PendingIntent.......");
        return pi;
    }
```